# Flutter Google Oauth2 signIn how to get _idToken

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am currently working on flutter app and I need to integrate google login. I am using google cloud Oauth and so far I integrated google login. But the issue is in the success response from google the _idtoken is null. Why I don't get the _idtoken

I need the _idToken to authenticate user from backend. What should I do

Below is my main.dart file

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_2/api/google_signin_api.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: signIn, child: const Text("Click"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  Future signIn() async {
    final user = await GoogleSignInApi.login();
    //print(user.idtoken)
    inspect(user);
  }
}
```

Below is google_signin_api.dart file

```
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class GoogleSignInApi {
  static final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  static Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> login() async {
    return _googleSignIn.signIn();
  }
}
```

this is the success response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug0UR.png)

Comment: show what you try to do in your code . give the code part

Comment: i'm using google_sign_in : https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in (official flutter plugin).. it works very well

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and include [example]

Comment: @Idriss how can I get google-services.json without using firebase. I only use google cloud console

Comment: @TasnuvaTavasumoshin I think the issue is I cannot get google-services.json from google cloud console. I am not using a firebase. How can I get google-services.json?

Comment: you can get it from firebase console